# Crash copying NSArray into NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to copy NSArray into NSMutableArray using the below code, but it crashes with the uncaught exception error.

Actual Response Array Result:

```
dataroot = (
    1,
    2,
    3
);
```

Code:

```
@interface MobileTestViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *mainMutArray ;
}
@end

@implementation MobileTestViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mainMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

NSMutableArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

NSArray *dataarray = [responseArray valueForKey:@“dataroot”];
mainMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: dataarray];

@end
```

Error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000013'

How can I properly copy that array into a NSMutableArray.

Comment: Your problem is not when you create your mutable array. How is `responseArray` being created?

Comment: dataroot =     (
         1,
         2,
         3
     );

Comment: Seems like you're confusing arrays and dictionaries... Why are you calling `valueForKey:` on an array? You don't index into arrays with string keys, you use integer indices...

Comment: This line `NSArray *dataarray = [responseArray valueForKey:@“dataroot”];` is unnecessary because you already have an array in `responseArray`, but it's an `NSArray`, not a mutable array. Just get rid of that line and modify the last line to use `responseArray` instead of `dataarray`

Comment: @Mike It is possible and useful to use KVC on arrays, even it is obviously wrong in this case.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Please explain a use-case where that makes sense.

Comment: @Mike Browse through my answers. There are several cases.  Or simply google. That is, why they overwrite the KVC methods in `NSArray`.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad My point is that there's clearly no reason to use KVO in this context especially when the OP clearly doesn't understand arrays vs dictionaries. Introducing KVO into the mix is likely going to lead to more misunderstandings. When reading and writing to arrays, 99.9% of the time the normal accessors are sufficient and KVO is unnecessary.

Comment: @mike My comment was: *@Mike It is possible and useful to use KVC on arrays, **even it is obviously wrong in this case**.* BTW: I talked about KV*C*, not KV*O*. KVO on arrays is really important. This is what array controllers are for. I think you are mixing up things.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're confusing `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. Is the object you get from the JSON serialization is array or a dictionary? Use the debugger or log what kind of class this is:

`NSMutableArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];`

If it's an array, the following code with crash as you don't index into arrays using string keys, you use integer indexes.

`NSArray *dataarray = [responseArray valueForKey:@“dataroot”];`

If the original object is a dictionary, try this code:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];

if (!responseDictionary) {
   // handle error
}

NSArray *dataArray = responseDictionary[@"dataroot"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use "**mutablecopy**" at the end of NSMutableArray allocation to solve the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Go for object for key method..

```
NSArray *dataarray = [responseArray objectForKey:@“dataroot”];
```

mainMutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: dataarray];

Hope it works...

Comment: Why would you call `objectForKey:` on an array? That will crash.

Comment: objectForKey method is for dictionary not array, for array we use ObjectAtIndex